# How to disable/hide the edit form that pops up after uploading new file into Document Set (SP 2016)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, 2016, document-set

I have created a Document Set Content Type named "Contract" with 2 shared columns (Start Date, End Date). I have also created a Document Library named "Contracts" which use this content Type.

I have created a new contract "Contract 1" based on the "Contract" Content Type then I have uploaded a word document within the "Contract 1" Document Set, then a Edit form popped up asking for updating the Start Date and End Date properties but these 2 properties have already inherited the values of the document set's properties and I dont want the values of these 2 properties to be updated at the file level (I want them to be always the same as the values of the Document Set 's properties)

So I am asking you if there is a way to prevent the user from changing the properties values of the uploaded document, so that they always stay the same as the ones inherited from the document set which it belongs to.

Thanks,

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my research, we cannot hide or disable the Edit Properties Form, it is by design. However, we can let the document inherit the property value of the Document set it belongs to.

**Please following steps:**

1.Set "Contract 1" Start Date is 2021/7/1 and End Date is 2021/7/31 5PM

[image]

2.Click on **Library Settings** >> scroll to **Content Types** sections, click on "**Contract**" content type

[image]

3.On the List Content Type page, click on **Document Set settings**

[image]

4.On the Document Set Settings page, scroll to **Shared Columns** section, and select **Start Date** and **End Date** option

[image]

5.When you upload a file to the document set, you will find that the document will automatically inherit the Start Date and End Date of the Document Set

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @EchoDu_MSFT for your help